# Anscombe transform & Anderson-Darling test failure

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, random-generation, anderson-darling-test

I created a synthetic constant image (all the pixel values are the same) on which I generated a Poisson distribution using a Poisson noise generator, with mean values set to input pixel values.

Then, I applied the Anscombe transform and checked if the output distribution fit the normal distribution by using the Anderson-Darling test with p=0.05.

Surprisingly, all the tests failed (I generated several Poisson distributions), do you have any explanation for this? Should we expect that the tests succeed (as the Anscombe transform is supposed to yield an APPROXIMATE normal distribution)?

Comment: I find the notion that a test is somehow "failing" when it correctly rejects non-normality to border on the perverse.

Answer (score 4):

The Anderson-Darling test is a test of **exact** normality, your transformation is supposed to give **approximate** normality, so the null hypothesis for AD is false and the correct decision is to reject the null.

Also note that the AD (and other) tests are rule out tests, if they reject the null then that means your data is not consistent with the null hypothesis of exact normality.  If the test does not reject the null hypothesis that **does not** mean that the data is normal, it may be (probably is) that you do not have enough power to find the difference.

The real issue is how good is your approximation or is the data normal enough?  This is the much more interesting question, but the standard normality tests do not answer this question.  Plots can help you get a better feel for this, but the final decision is going to be subjective.

Answer (score 0):

With large sample sizes, the [Anderson-Darling test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) is [prone to reject very large samples](https://www.isixsigma.com/topic/sample-size-for-anderson-darling-normality-test/) from otherwise acceptable distributions.

If you are dealing with thousands of data points, the  [Ryan-Joiner](http://www.statsref.com/HTML/index.html?ryan-joiner.html) or [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) tests should be used.

**Note**: Changing the test should be something that, in the future, is done based on sample size information and not as a result of choosing hypothesis tests until you are successful.

Another word of caution: it is possible to change tests to something more robust for a larger sample size even though the data looks decent.  Using the data from [this discussion on the topic of hypothesis tests](https://www.r-bloggers.com/normality-tests-don%E2%80%99t-do-what-you-think-they-do/), the large "normal" data still fails.  (I tested the data with a stabilized normal probability plot, and it becomes apparent that the seemingly normal data actually fails on multiple points, and not even in the tails.)

Comment: I cannot fathom the rationale for substituting a less powerful test for a more powerful one: that seems only like a way to hide what's going on.  If A-D says the data aren't normal, they likely aren't--so deal with it by understanding what that means, as discussed by Greg Snow in his answer.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found out that if we have a large number of samples (cf. Wikipedia), AD test can fail. Hence, I tested this with  100 samples and the test succeeded.

Comment: Are you really comfortable with the practice of deciding that you have too much data because you don't get the answer you like, so you throw away data until you get the answer you want?  If this were good science then we could use this to prove that global warming (or other pet/hot topic) is real or nothing to worry about by just choosing the appropriate null hypothesis and throwing away data until we do not reject the null.

Comment: Why not just test with two samples, then, and be done with it?  That test will *always* succeed!  The motivation for using any normality test seems rather elusive at this point.  What is certain, though, is that if you are flexible enough to keep applying a test to smaller and smaller subsets of your sample until you get a satisfactory result, then your test isn't doing anything at all (at least nothing good...).

Comment: Indeed; why use consistent tests at all, if you dislike rejecting false nulls?